# Differential equation : $y'=x^2y-y+x^2-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, we have the following differential equation :  $y'=x^2y-y+x^2-1$

I do know what's the general solution. What I'm wondering, how would I find the constant solution in this equation (If they exist?)

We can put the differential equation in this form : $y'=(x^2-1)(y+1)$

Would the only constant solution be $-1$? I know this may be a basic thing, but I just got introduced to this matter, so I want to be sure. Thank you!

Comment: Yep! You're quite right. An equivalent condition for a function being constant is that its derivative is zero everywhere. Setting $y'=0$, you see that $y(x)$ must be $-1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

The particular solution y=-1 draw us to change of function : $y(x)=f(x)-1$
$$f'=x^2(f-1)-(f-1)+x^2-1=(x^2-1)f$$
This is a separable ODE :
$$\frac{f'}{f}=x^2-1$$
$$\ln|f|=\frac{x^3}{3}-x+constant$$
$$f=C \exp\left(\frac{x^3}{3}-x\right)$$
$$y=-1+C \exp\left(\frac{x^3}{3}-x\right)$$
If $C\neq 0$ we see that $y$ is function on $x$, hense is not constant. So $y$ is constant only if $C=0$ and then $y=-1$.